# Clustering - Auto ML Solutions

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, predictive-modeling, statistics

I intend to use clustering for my problem grouping customers together. However, instead of me manually tuning hyperparameters and CV, I would like to know is there anyway to do the clustering using Auto-ML packages.

The auto-ml packages that I found online don't seem to support clustering and are mainly focused on classification and regression.

So, is there any Auto-ML solutions for the clustering? can provide me the list of auto-ML packages please?

Comment: That's... not a good idea. You will have to think about your problems at some point, computational power will not save you. This is even more true for clustering, which is much more subjective by design than supervised learning.

Comment: @user2974951 - Thank you for the response. But I currently wish to assess the problem for POC phase. So, wanted to do a quick try and find out..Is it possible to let me know if you know any packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classification predictions can be evaluated using accuracy, whereas regression predictions cannot. Regression predictions can be evaluated using root mean squared error, whereas classification predictions cannot. Clustering is totally different! You are not looking for some accuracy measure or precision of prediction using a supervised technique, but rather, clustering is used to group data points having similar characteristics. This is why it is known as unsupervised learning.

Try Mean Shift for automatically detecting the optimal number of clusters. Here's an example. Hopefully you can adapt it for your specific use.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

# #############################################################################
# Generate sample data
centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1], [1, -1], [1, -1]]
X, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=10000, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.2)

# #############################################################################
# Compute clustering with MeanShift

# The following bandwidth can be automatically detected using
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(X, quantile=0.6, n_samples=5000)

ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=True)
ms.fit(X)
labels = ms.labels_
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_

labels_unique = np.unique(labels)
n_clusters_ = len(labels_unique)

print("number of estimated clusters : %d" % n_clusters_)

# #############################################################################
# Plot result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()

colors = cycle('bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk')
for k, col in zip(range(n_clusters_), colors):
    my_members = labels == k
    cluster_center = cluster_centers[k]
    plt.plot(X[my_members, 0], X[my_members, 1], col + '.')
    plt.plot(cluster_center[0], cluster_center[1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)
plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, try this.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
  
# We will be using the make_blobs method 
# in order to generate our own data. 
  
clusters = [[2, 2, 2], [7, 7, 7], [5, 13, 13]] 
  
X, _ = make_blobs(n_samples = 150, centers = clusters, 
                                   cluster_std = 0.60) 
   
# After training the model, We store the 
# coordinates for the cluster centers 
ms = MeanShift() 
ms.fit(X) 
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_ 
   
# Finally We plot the data points 
# and centroids in a 3D graph. 
fig = plt.figure() 
  
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection ='3d') 
  
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2], marker ='o') 
  
ax.scatter(cluster_centers[:, 0], cluster_centers[:, 1], 
           cluster_centers[:, 2], marker ='x', color ='red', 
           s = 300, linewidth = 5, zorder = 10) 
  
plt.show()
```

[image]

There are a few clustering methodologies that help you choose the optimal number of clusters automatically. Check out the link below for some ideas of how to move forward with your project.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

Comment: thanks for the response. upvoted. But, I was looking for some auto ML solutions like Tpot, pycaret etc which can do clustering automaticalling and return results.

Comment: Wow. I have never even heard of those things. Thanks for the insight! I'll look into that stuff later today!

Comment: Hi, I created another related post - can you help me ? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/109713/comparing-two-groups-at-large-scale